# Why are PolarTicks displaying as decimals instead of fractions in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm building a graphing polar graphing palette to create graphs quickly.  I setup a `PolarTicks[]` option to take in fractions using a slider in `Manipulate[]` that varies over fractions (not decimals).  I'm not sure why the polar ticks are showing up as decimals on my graph.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
Manipulate[PolarPlot[, {θ , 0, 2 Pi },
  PlotRange -> {{-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}, {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}}, 
  Ticks -> None,
  PolarAxes -> axes,
  PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, multi], Range[0, 3/2, (3/2)/r]},
  PolarTicks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, multi], Range[0, 3/2, (3/2)/r]}

  ], {{axes, True, "Axes"}, {True, False}}, {multi, {Pi/12, Pi/6, 
   Pi/4, Pi/2, Pi, 2 Pi}, ControlType -> Slider}, {r, 1, 10, 1} , 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

I notice that if I keep my code and change  the control type to `SetterBar` I do get fractions.  It this a bug with `Slider`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display as fraction

```
tor[x_] := Row[{Numerator@x, "/", Denominator@x}]
```

Also added `PlotRangePadding` (numbers didn't fully display) and made sliders move

```
Manipulate[

  PolarPlot[, {θ, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotRange -> {{-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}, {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}},
  PlotRangePadding-> 0.5,
  PolarAxes -> axes,
  PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, multi], Range[0, 3/2, (3/2)/r]},
  PolarTicks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, multi], 
    Transpose[{#, tor /@ #}] &[Range[0, 3/2, (3/2)/r]]}],

 {{axes, True, "Axes"}, {True, False}},
 {multi, Pi/12, 2 Pi, Pi/12},
 {r, 1, 10, 1},
 TrackedSymbols :> {axes, multi, r},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Glad that I could help. I assume it's a `PolarPlot` design decision because you can't display many rationals on the r-axis (therefore my trick to write them in a row).